# How to identify or change labels created by for loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to change the configs on some of my labels which were created by a `for loop` but do not know how to call the labels. My code looks like this:

```
hand_info_labels = [
    'Hand Info', str(self.sb), 'Players',
     str(self.sb), 'Pre-flop', str(self.sb),
     'Flop', str(self.sb), 'Turn',
      str(self.sb), 'River', str(self.sb)]

for label in hand_info_labels:
    ttk.Label(
        hh_lblfrm, text=label).grid(
        column=0, sticky=tk.W)
```

How can you call these labels? I was thinking something like `hand_info_labels['Hand Info'].config(font=("Courier", 44))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the labels are different the easiest way is to save each label widget to a dict, which you then can use to specify any label.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()

hh_lblfrm = tk.Frame(root)
hh_lblfrm.grid()

hand_info_labels = ['Hand Info', 'Players', 'Turn', 'River']

label_dict = {}
for row, label in enumerate(hand_info_labels):
    widget = ttk.Label(hh_lblfrm, text=label)
    widget.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
    label_dict[label] = widget

# Test to change config on one of the labels
label_dict['Players'].config(background='salmon')
```

And if you want to change a list of labels you can use a loop:

```
# Test to change config on list of labels
widgets_to_change = ['Hand Info', 'Turn']
for widget in widgets_to_change:
    label_dict[widget].config(background='khaki')
```

If some labels are the same you can use a list instead but then you will have to remember the index of each label.

Comment: Great response and awesome way to clean up the code. I was going to ask about `enumerate` but a quick Google search shows that the enumerate function is a way to loop over something with an automatic counter.

Comment: If I wanted to change multiple labels in the `label_dict['Players'].config(background='salmon')` line, would the best way to be using a list?

Comment: I updated my example with how to change a list of labels.